# Measure traffic from apache access log

Tags: linux, apache, logging

Is there any way to measure how much traffic there were used in one Apache log file?

Format:

```
66.249.72.214 - - [05/Nov/2011:12:47:37 +0200] "GET /produktas/565638 HTTP/1.1" 200 4699 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

How I understand `4699` are bytes that were transferred excluding headers.

I need a simple solution (maybe a little bash script) to sum bytes in every log's line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. I tested it on a local file but cannot tell if it works on all configurations/locales/...

```
cat apache.log | perl -e 'my $sum=0; while(<>) { my ($traffic) = m/\[.+\] ".+" \d+ (\d+)/; $sum += $traffic}; print "$sum\n"'
```

**Update Jan 2017:** Meanwhile I've learned some more Perl and that's how I'd do it today:

```
cat apache.log | perl -nE '/\[.+\] ".+" \d+ (\d+)/; $sum += $1; END {say $sum}'
```

Comment: Thank you! I have modified it a little bit to show in gigabytes: [code]cat access.log | perl -e 'my $sum=0; while(<>) { my ($traffic) = m/\[.+\] ".+" \d+ (\d+)/; $sum += $traffic}; printf("%.3f/1024/1024/1024); print " GB\n"'[/code]

Answer (score 5):

For detailed log file monitoring and actual bandwidth  usage, go for [AWStats](https://awstats.sourceforge.io).

It takes the Apache log file as input and give you very detailed analysis of the visitors and bandwidth, with graphs.

You can also try [GoAccess](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/).

Answer (score 4):

**Apache Access Log — Global bandwidth usage :**

```
awk '{ s += $10 } END { print "Total ", s/1024/1024 " Mo", "- Moyenne ", s/NR/1024/1024 " Mo", "- Accès ", NR }' access.log
```

**And for a file :**

```
grep NAME_OF_RESOURCE_HERE /var/log/apache2/access.log* | awk '{ s += $10 } END { print "Total ", s/1024/1024 " Mo", "- Moyenne ", s/NR/1024/1024 " Mo", "- Accès ", NR }'
```

**You get something like this :** Total  301.985 Mo - Moyenne  0.0430055 Mo - Accès  7022

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [apachetop](http://www.jeremyjones.com/apachetop/) utility, try to install from APT with next command:

```
sudo apt-get install apachetop
```

And then run it with command:

```
sudo apachetop -f /path/to/access.log
```

And you are rock! :)

Answer (score 1):

We needed to get the traffic of last X days. I’m really not into perl, so what i did is:

```
zcat $(find -name yourvhost_access.log*.gz -mtime -3 2>/dev/null| xargs ) \ 
| awk '$10 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $10}' \
| paste -sd+ \
| bc
```

Steps:

1. find last 3 achived accesslogs
2. print position 10 if its a Number - payload should be here
3. put it together with "+"
4. calculate